# Spring Boot application shutting down immediately mentioning ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

The only error it mentioned was that there was an error starting ApplicationContext.

Here's the relevant code and output:

**TodoListApplication.java**

```
    package com.foobar.TodoList;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import com.foobar.TodoList.model.User;
    import com.foobar.TodoList.model.User.TodoItem;
    import com.foobar.TodoList.repository.UserRepository;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class TodoListApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TodoListApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        List<TodoItem> todoItems = new ArrayList<TodoItem>();
        todoItems.add(new TodoItem("mow the lawn", false));

        this.userRepository.save(new User("Joe", "password", todoItems));
    }
}
```

**User.java**

```
package com.isanoui.TodoList.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    
    // @Column(name = "todos")
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private List<TodoItem> todos = new ArrayList<TodoItem>();

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "todo_item")
    public static class TodoItem {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        protected long id;

        @Column(name = "todo")
        protected String todo;

        @Column(name = "completed")
        protected boolean completed;

        public TodoItem() {}

        public TodoItem(String todo, boolean completed) {
            // super();
            this.todo = todo;
            this.completed = completed;
        }

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getTodo() {
            return todo;
        }

        public void setTodo(String todo) {
            this.todo = todo;
        }

        public boolean isCompleted() {
            return completed;
        }

        public void setCompleted(boolean completed) {
            this.completed = completed;
        }
    }

    public User() {}

    public User(String name, String password, List<TodoItem> todos) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.todos = todos;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<TodoItem> getTodos() {
        return todos;
    }

    public void setTodos(TodoItem todoItem) {
        this.todos.add(todoItem);
    }
}
```

**Console Log**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.1)

2021-01-15 03:16:36.526  INFO 17160 --- [           main] c.isanoui.TodoList.TodoListApplication   : Starting TodoListApplication using Java 15.0.1 on Isa with PID 17160 (C:\Users\Aissa\Downloads\TodoList\target\classes started by Aissa in c:\Users\Aissa\Downloads\TodoList)
2021-01-15 03:16:36.528  INFO 17160 --- [           main] c.isanoui.TodoList.TodoListApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-01-15 03:16:37.071  INFO 17160 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-01-15 03:16:37.123  INFO 17160 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 45 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-01-15 03:16:37.625  INFO 17160 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-01-15 03:16:37.635  INFO 17160 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-01-15 03:16:37.635  INFO 17160 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.41]
2021-01-15 03:16:37.759  INFO 17160 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-01-15 03:16:37.759  INFO 17160 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1194 ms
2021-01-15 03:16:37.911  INFO 17160 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-01-15 03:16:38.069  INFO 17160 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-01-15 03:16:38.120  INFO 17160 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-01-15 03:16:38.175  INFO 17160 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.25.Final
2021-01-15 03:16:38.312  INFO 17160 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-01-15 03:16:38.436  INFO 17160 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2021-01-15 03:16:39.019  INFO 17160 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-01-15 03:16:39.025  INFO 17160 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-01-15 03:16:39.319  WARN 17160 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-01-15 03:16:39.435  INFO 17160 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-01-15 03:16:39.608  WARN 17160 --- [           main] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
2021-01-15 03:16:39.722  INFO 17160 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-01-15 03:16:39.733  INFO 17160 --- [           main] c.isanoui.TodoList.TodoListApplication   : Started TodoListApplication in 3.472 seconds (JVM running for 4.008)
2021-01-15 03:16:39.807  INFO 17160 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2021-01-15 03:16:39.813  INFO 17160 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-01-15 03:16:39.831 ERROR 17160 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:807) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
 SpringApplication.java
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:788) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
 SpringApplication.java
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
 SpringApplication.java
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
 SpringApplication.java
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
 SpringApplication.java
    at com.isanoui.TodoList.TodoListApplication.main(TodoListApplication.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
 TodoListApplication.java
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.isanoui.TodoList.model.User$TodoItem; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.isanoui.TodoList.model.User$TodoItem
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:371) ~[spring-orm-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
 EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:235) ~[spring-orm-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
 HibernateJpaDialect.java
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:566) ~[spring-orm-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
 JpaTransactionManager.java
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
 AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
 AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
 TransactionAspectSupport.java
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
 TransactionAspectSupport.java
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
 TransactionInterceptor.java
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
 ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
 PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
 ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
 CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
 ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
 ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
 ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
 JdkDynamicAopProxy.java
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.isanoui.TodoList.TodoListApplication.run(TodoListApplication.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
 TodoListApplication.java
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:804) ~[spring-boot-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
 SpringApplication.java
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.isanoui.TodoList.model.User$TodoItem
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
 ExceptionConverterImpl.java
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
 ExceptionConverterImpl.java
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
 ExceptionConverterImpl.java
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1366) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
 SessionImpl.java
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:453) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
 SessionImpl.java
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3212) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
 SessionImpl.java
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2380) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
 SessionImpl.java
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
 JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
 JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
 JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
 JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
 TransactionImpl.java
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562) ~[spring-orm-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
 JpaTransactionManager.java
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.isanoui.TodoList.model.User$TodoItem
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:347) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
 ForeignKeys.java
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:507) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
 EntityType.java
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.nullSafeSet(EntityType.java:280) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
 EntityType.java
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.writeElement(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:930) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
 AbstractCollectionPersister.java
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1352) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
 AbstractCollectionPersister.java
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.OneToManyPersister.recreate(OneToManyPersister.java:187) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
 OneToManyPersister.java
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:52) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
 CollectionRecreateAction.java
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
 ActionQueue.java
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
 ActionQueue.java
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:723) ~[na:na]
 LinkedHashMap.java
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
 ActionQueue.java
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
 DefaultFlushEventListener.java
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
 EventListenerGroupImpl.java
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1362) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
 SessionImpl.java
    ... 30 common frames omitted

2021-01-15 03:16:39.862  INFO 17160 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-01-15 03:16:39.863  INFO 17160 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-01-15 03:16:39.863  INFO 17160 --- [           main] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2021-01-15 03:16:39.870  INFO 17160 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-01-15 03:16:39.872  INFO 17160 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Note: java version in pom file says 11, but I have jdk 15, don't think that matters though

Note 2: I did `debug=true` in `application.properties` but doesn't actually start it, just more detailed output

Comment: Stacktrace says very clearly whats wrong. You are trying to save `User` without saving `TodoItem` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the following

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.isanoui.TodoList.model.User$TodoItem
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:347) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.25.Final.jar:5.4.25.Final]
 ForeignKeys.java
```

You can make the OneToMany or ManyToOne cascade to all with

```
// @Column(name = "todos")
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private List<TodoItem> todos = new ArrayList<TodoItem>();
```

Or you can as described in comment to save first the inner object and then the outer.

```
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    TodoItem item = new TodoItem("mow the lawn", false);
    this.itemRepository.save(item); 

    List<TodoItem> todoItems = new ArrayList<TodoItem>();
    todoItems.add(item);
    this.userRepository.save(new User("Joe", "password", todoItems));
}
```

Comment: I just added my model code that shows the OneToMany relation. I should add the cascade parameter?

Comment: you added controller not User.java

Comment: ah sorry, fixed

Comment: that worked, tyvm! gonna look into cascadetype

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused, becuase you want to invoke the CommandLineRunner. I always use it by excplicitly invoking CommandLineRunner bean. In your case that would be it:

```
@Bean
    public CommandLineRunner prepopulateDB(UserRepository userRepository) {
        return args -> {
    List<TodoItem> todoItems = new ArrayList<TodoItem>();
    todoItems.add(new TodoItem("mow the lawn", false));

    userRepository.save(new User("Joe", "password", todoItems));
        };
    }
```

Comment: that gives me the same error message unfortunately

Comment: Ok, now looking at the stacktrace - I think that the problem is you try to save user, but the TodoItem is not saved. You need to save them in the correct order

Answer (score 0):

the error tell :

```
 object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.isanoui.TodoList.model.User$TodoItem; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
```

i guess you have a OneToMany relation between User and TodoItem that the relation between them are not correct, you flush session from hibernate but before that you may save the entity. (i think you should correct the relation between 2 entity and it may correct if not, double check how the object persistent working)

Comment: I just added my model code that show the @OneToMany relation, you are correct to assume that